# Tool to search office docs in SVN repository

Tags: svn, search, lucene, indexing, ms-office

I store more than just source code in my subversion repos.
I would like to have a search tool which handled doc, doxc, xls, xlsx, pdf, etc... like what [VoilaSVN](http://arcetis.voilasvn.com/main/EN/products.html) did, however it appears to have dropped off the end of the earth?

Forcing a checkout of the entire repo and use a local (to the PC) search indexer is one option, but due to the size of the repo it is not practical.
Also this has the drawback that it will only provide results on the revision of SVN that the working copy is at.

Are there any tools out there which use something like Lucene to index more than just plain text within SVN?
I would prefer open source, but I would consider a proprietary solution.

Answer (score 0):

One such tool is [SupoSE](http://www.supose.org/projects/supose/wiki) -- I haven't tested it much, though